# How can I check if gmail is enabled or disabled

Tags: android

I'm checking if gmail app is installed on the device this way:

```
public boolean isGmailInstalled(String uri) {

PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
boolean app_installed = false;

try {           
pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
app_installed = true;
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
app_installed = false;
}
return app_installed;
}

OnClick

boolean installed = isGmailInstalled("com.google.android.gm");

if (installed) {
}
```

But I don't know how to check if it's enabled or disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Intent.resolveActivity` before launching the app. Something like:

```
    if (yourIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(yourIntent);
    }
```

To check if the app is enabled, you can use `PackageManager.getApplicationInfo`.

```
ApplicationInfo ai = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("com.google.android.gm", 0);
// ai.enabled will return `true` if it's enabled and `false` otherwise
```

Comment: Can you specify it more or use that in my onClick code above

Comment: Well, I assumed you were checking to see if it was installed before opening the app from an `Intent`. Using the above code is actually all you need. But I made an edit to check to see if it's enabled.